# gettext filter does nothing

Tags: filters, translation

According to the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext), I can use the `gettext` filter to change translated output.

So, when I add this to the functions.php of my theme, all translated content should vanish:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'erase_everything', 1000, 3 );
function erase_everything( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
    return '';
}
```

However, everything is still translated correctly. How can I find the reason for this?

Comment: What are you using to translate your content?

Comment: @czerspalace, I use qtranslateX.

Comment: I just discovered that my filter affects the admin, but not the frontend.

Comment: Is this code inside some other action?

Comment: Where did you define this code?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi, @kraftner, this code ist not inside any other action, but simply a top level statement in the `functions.php` file of my theme.